# Animations problems c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, sprite

I've been trying to create a game on unity and while I was trying to do the animations I'm realizing that I don't have any idea why my code is not working.

```
//Animacion
if(!Input.GetKey("left") && !Input.GetKey("right"))
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Moving", false);            
}

if(Input.GetKey("right"))
{
     gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Moving", true);            
}

if(Input.GetKey("left"))
{
     gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Moving", true);            
}
```

I am not getting any error

Comment: Have you ensured that the code inside any of those `if` statements are red?

Comment: Yeah, I dont get any error but i just solve it changing the if

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply use this instead:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Moving", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0);
```

But to fix your own code you can do this:

```
if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Moving", false);
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Moving", true);
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Moving", true);
}
```